# Error while sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, error, command-line

```
  Replace App And Pub Folder of Theme In Magento2. 


  After that Run Following Command : **sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade**


 Show Following error :

  > PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in
  > /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Phrase/__.php:15)
  > in /var/www/html/magento2/app/functions.php on line 22
```

Comment: compare your app/functions.php old and new file or replace new to old file app/functions.php
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258339/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-previously-declared-in-vendor-magento-f

Answer (score 0):

Compare your `app/functions.php` code with the code below and if not same replace it with this one

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Create value-object \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 * @deprecated The global function __() is now loaded via Magento Framework, the below require is only
 *             for backwards compatibility reasons and this file will be removed in a future version
 * @see        Magento\Framework\Phrase\__.php
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ShortMethodName)
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
if (!function_exists('__')) {
    function __()
    {
        $argc = func_get_args();

        $text = array_shift($argc);
        if (!empty($argc) && is_array($argc[0])) {
            $argc = $argc[0];
        }

        return new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($text, $argc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace with below contents of **`app/functions.php`** file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Create value-object \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 * @deprecated The global function __() is now loaded via Magento Framework, the below require is only
 *             for backwards compatibility reasons and this file will be removed in a future version
 * @see        Magento\Framework\Phrase\__.php
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ShortMethodName)
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
if (!function_exists('__')) {
    function __()
    {
        $argc = func_get_args();

        $text = array_shift($argc);
        if (!empty($argc) && is_array($argc[0])) {
            $argc = $argc[0];
        }

        return new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($text, $argc);
    }
}
```

**hope its work for you**